# Can this expression be made more accurate and not return negative values?

Tags: precision, numerical-methods

I'm using Julia but I'm sure that solutions will mostly translate across different languages.

I would like to calculate the following expression in `Float64` precision for positive values of $T$.

[image]

`a` is a positive constant.  The expression inside the square root should always be positive but as `T` approach zero, the result occasionally comes up negative because of numerical precision issues.

```
julia> α=1/4.0; map( T -> ( 4 * exp(-α * T) - 3 - exp( -2α * T ) + 2α * T ), 10.0.^(-10:0) )
11-element Vector{Float64}:
 -4.137018548132909e-18
 -4.137018546840439e-17
  3.038735495922355e-17
 -2.512379594116203e-16
  4.113329634720811e-17
  1.8928899382176026e-16
  1.0552627836227929e-14
  1.041483522687403e-11
  1.0397158019953556e-8
  1.022361261644733e-5
  0.00867247257298609
```

Don't have the same problem (for the same values) when calculating using `BigFloat`s.

```
julia> α=BigFloat(1/4.0); map( T -> ( 4 * exp(-α * T) - 3 - exp( -2α * T ) + 2α * T ), 10.0.^(-10:0) )
11-element Vector{BigFloat}:
 1.041666666647135530517511139334179132983501942809441564565600382453160881163658e-32
 1.041666666471354361319426381902535606415006422809427598976663299435084708258933e-29
 1.041666664713541734328314928659467024540737963331449636847040682408936614887116e-26
 1.041666647135417166709396893449432138811473447225776037995767356684771923939405e-23
 1.041666471354189311710850303868877685043857627660615702953528423064833434922657e-20
 1.04166471354394556609940068924547895770393434711169898595204995967864381931136e-17
 1.041647135644529365261489400892467181239989440055364005317784883808499181692089e-14
 1.041471376951090709983860760560291162481306334994613272150860749219930444115473e-11
 1.039715818279496102769801850953898783936741961589734116598630369857383947507474e-08
 1.022361261666541821235659358423414459600515733306470783618814653113646037198644e-05
 0.008672472572986049376881532922102135745171026217378941282377306337925928800328869
```

Is there some way to modify this calculation to improve precision and prevent this problem while still using `Float64`s?

Comment: This is numerical analysis. Expand the expression under the radical into Taylor series around zero, discard quadratic terms, and simplify. If that collapses, then keep the quadratic terms and discard cubics.

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
4*z - 3 - z^2 = (3-z)*(z-1)
```

and use

```
e^(-aT)-1 = expm1(-aT)
```

which computes this factor with full relative precision as `-aT*(1+O(aT))`.

Using gnuplot to visualize the difference:

[image]

Comment: Yes, that happens because numerical second derivatives are not guaranteed by the IEEE implementations, only first derivatives at zero. One can decompose the expression also as `-(exp(-x)-1)^2+2(exp(-x)-1+x)` and the quadratic (as also the higher-degree) polynomial coefficient in the `exp` implementation is different from the Taylor coefficient, as the optimization is for a small error over an interval, and not at zero. So in that sense, switching over to a term-wise or overall Taylor expansion is necessary to keep the fullest possible accuracy close to zero.

Answer (score 2):

The root cause of the issues seen with the original function is subtractive cancellation, that is, the effective subtraction of two quantities of similar magnitude. There are some general heuristics of how to deal with such situations: (1) For computations involving `exp()` near zero, use `expm1()` instead. (2) Convert subtractions into divisions or multiplications (3) Use fused multiply-add at the place  where subtractive cancellation occurs, provided one of the two operands involved is a product. This works because FMA incorporates the double-wide unrounded product into the sum.

After coming up with a suitable mitigating re-arrangement, I noticed that loss of accuracy persisted for `a * T` smaller than about 2<sup>-6</sup>. A standard approach for such issues for arguments very close to zero is to attempt a Taylor series expansion. I computed the first six terms of the Taylor expansion numerically, using a multi-precision library configured for 130 decimal digits. A faster alternative would have been to make use of Wolfram Alpha.

I should note that I approached the error-reducing replacement in a pedestrian fashion. Lutz Lehmann found a re-arrangement that is more elegant, more efficient, and does not require FMA; see [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75564577/780717).

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

#define USE_NJ (1)
#define FUNC   accurate_func

double accurate_func (double a, double T)
{
    double r, u = a * T;
    // use Taylor series expansion near zero
    if (u <= 0.015625) {  // 1/64
        double u3 = u * u * u;
        double p =  -1.0 / 160.0;
        p = p * u + 31.0 / 1260.0; 
        p = p * u -  1.0 / 12.0;
        p = p * u +  7.0 / 30.0;
        p = p * u -  1.0 / 2.0;
        p = p * u +  2.0 / 3.0;
        r = p * u3;
    } else {
#if USE_NJ // use exmp1() and fma() to mitigate subtractive cancellation
        double v = expm1 (u);
        double w = exp (-2 * u);
        r = fma (-3 * v * v, w, 2 * fma (-v, w, u));
#else // Lutz Lehmann's elegant arrangement
        double s = expm1 (-u);
        r = (2.0 - s) * s + 2 * u;
#endif
    }
    return sqrt (r);
}

double original_func (double a, double T)
{
    double u = a * T;
    return sqrt (4* exp (-u) - 3 - exp (-2 * u) + 2*u);
}

int main (void)
{
    double mpref [13] = {
        5.7981245368580744e-1, // 2^0
        2.4133627509989329e-1, // 2^-1
        9.3126111123497739e-2, // 2^-2
        3.4450359460776940e-2, // 2^-3
        1.2463894628395316e-2, // 2^-4
        4.4581489320727356e-3, // 2^-5
        1.5854164404162396e-3, // 2^-6
        5.6217040623145288e-4, // 2^-7
        1.9904830179668834e-4, // 2^-8
        7.0425736778377448e-5, // 2^-9
        2.4908375624050728e-5, // 2^-10
        8.8080530945851612e-6, // 2^-11
        3.1144021359546032e-6, // 2^-12
    };

    double mpref2 [13] = {
        5.7981245368580744e-1, // 2^0
        1.2341091904923634e+0, // 2^1
        2.2523159398554711e+0, // 2^2
        3.6057373362429543e+0, // 2^3
        5.3851648489290173e+0, // 2^4
        7.8102496759066576e+0, // 2^5
        1.1180339887498948e+1, // 2^6
        1.5905973720586866e+1, // 2^7
    };

    int i = 0;
    double a = 1.0;
    do {
        double T = 1.0 / (1 << i);
        printf ("i=%2d a*T=%23.16e  func=%23.16e  relerrfunc=% 15.8e\n", 
                i, a*T, FUNC(a,T), (FUNC(a,T) - mpref[i]) / mpref[i]);
        i++;
    } while (i < 13);
    printf ("\n");
    i = 0;
    do {
        double T = 1.0 * (1 << i);
        printf ("i=%2d a*T=%23.16e  func=%23.16e  relerrfunc=% 15.8e\n", 
                i, a*T, FUNC(a,T), (FUNC(a,T) - mpref2[i]) / mpref2[i]);
        i++;
    } while (i < 8);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm just a random Julia person, not a numericist, but I'd like to contribute what [Herbie](https://herbie.uwplse.org/), a tool to automatically improve floating point accuracy, gives you:

```
function f(a, T)
    t1 = Float64((T ^ 4.0) * -0.5)
    t2 = a ^ 4.0
    t3 = Float64(Float64(T * -2.0) + Float64(T * 2.0))
    t4 = a ^ 3.0
    t5 = Float64((T ^ 3.0) * 0.6666666666666666)
    t6 = log(exp(Float64(0.23333333333333334 * (Float64(T * a) ^ 5.0))))

    u1 = fma(t4, t5, t6)
    u2 = fma(t3, a, u1)
    return fma(t1, t2, u2)
end
```

(Herbie can directly generate Julia; I just reformatted the output from a one-liner to something more analysable.)

It even [generates you a proof](https://herbie.uwplse.org/demo/321f76e1b9fa152efad29ad2606ca92b13d03da3.1.6/graph.html) of why the transformation is correct.